# Snackbar inside Volley's onErrorResponse does not execute Action code

Tags: android, android-volley, android-snackbar

I'm using a `VolleyRequest` to pull data. However when there is an error is shows a message using a `Snackbar` to inform the user that the internet connection is slow and they can retry. However clicking the Action button does nothing, instead the Snackbar just disappears and does not call the method. The Snackbar is shown inside the `onErrorResponse()` of the request.
How can I go about this problem? Here is my code:

```
@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    Log.e(TAG, error.toString());

    hasInternet = false;
    snackbar = Snackbar.make(coordinator, "Slow internet connection detected", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
            .setAction("RETRY", new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                   makeRequest();
                }
            });
    snackbar.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    Log.e(TAG, error.toString());

    // Use getActivity().runOnUiThread(...) if it's a fragment.
    // In the case of activity
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            hasInternet = false;
            snackbar = Snackbar.make(coordinator, "Slow internet connection detected", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                    .setAction("RETRY", new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            makeRequest();
                        }
                    });
            snackbar.show();
        }
    }

}
```